# Javascript Detect click on Video Progressbar

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, event-handling

I'm trying to detect a Mouseclick on the Searchbar, of a HTML5 Video.

My code:

```js
var mouseDown = 0;

function mouseClickDown() {
  console.log("mouseDown")
    ++mouseDown;
}

function mouseClickUp() {
  console.log("mouseUp")
    --mouseDown;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-video">
  <video id="video" controls class="video">
    <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="controls">
    <progress class="progress-bar" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="videoProgressBar" onmouseup="mouseClickUp()" onmousedown="mouseClickDown()">0% played</progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the event doesn't get triggered if I click on the Searchbar.

Have anyone an Idea to detect this Events?

Comment: I made your snippet runnable right here in your question. If you run it, you'll see that it works. Maybe there is something else in your actual code that you are not telling us about? I see you're using `{{ video }}` in your HTML. Are you using a framework like VueJS, or some kind of templating engine? (it could affect the way it works)

Comment: I'm using Flask, so I'm using Jinja as Templating engine

Comment: I've changed the Video in the Snippet, so you can Play it from the Snippet